# Let $M$ be a subgroup of $G$, how do we get the property that if $x\in M$ then $xM=M$?

Tags: group-theory

> Let $M$ be a subgroup of $G$, how do we get the property that if $x\in M$ then $xM=M$?

As far as I know the multiplication is only defined to be self-contained in $M$, how do I know that if I pick some $m\in M$ then there exists a $m'\in M$ such that $m=xm'$?

Comment: Because both $m$ and $x^{-1}$ are in $M$.

Comment: P.S. Please include your question in the body of the message, not just the title. The post should not depend on the title/subject for context.

Comment: I can pick $m'=x^{-1}m$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x $ and $m $ are in $M $, $x^{-1}m $ is also in $M $. Take $m'=x^{-1}m$.